# How do I turn a Safari Webarchive file into a folder?

Tags: software-recommendation, safari

I understand a Safari webarchive is a single file with the source code and other resources from a web page concatenated into a single file. I found a [Macworld article from 2006](http://www.macworld.com/article/1050198/webarchivefolderizer.html) describing a program that does just this, but the link to the program is no longer current.

Is there any currently available software that can convert a Safari webarchive file into a more standard format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### [WebArchiveExtractor](https://github.com/robrohan/WebArchiveExtractor)

I recommend WebArchiveExtractor. You can drag .webarchive files to this app which will extract the file into its individual files in a folder.

[image]

You can customise the output in Preferences, including setting a custom index file name:

[image]

---

WebArchiveExtractor is open source on GitHub

As of June 2021, it does build perfectly in Xcode (from the link above) and works very well.

Comment: WebArchive Extractor isn't working for me as of 9 Dec 2019. I'm using macOS 10.14.4 (18E226) Mojave on a .webarchive file from Safari.

Comment: It does seem to work perfectly as of June 2021, thanks for the tip here !

Comment: it works perfectly as of 20 June 2020, try this link https://github.com/robrohan/WebArchiveExtractor/releases

Comment: Works fine in Big Sur / M1

Comment: Latest build doesn't work for me. MacBook Pro M2 Sonoma 14.1.1.

Answer (score 21):

> Is there any currently available software that can convert a Safari
>   webarchive file into a more standard format?

If you are comfortable with command line, there is a tool `textutil` on Mac OS for converting webarchive file to txt, html, rtf, rtfd, doc, docx, wordml, or odt.

Example:
`textutil -convert html /Users/USERNAME/NAME.webarchive`

---

For converting webarchive file to pdf, try "Wondershare PDF Editor for Mac". http://www.wondershare.com/pdf/how-to-convert-webarchive-to-pdf.html

Comment: The `textutil` command line tool only extracts the top-level html file, and not the CSS or scripts that are also part of the webarchive. (Which is really the whole point of the webarchive.) I have not found a good alternate way to do this from the command line.

Comment: @Stephen WebArchiveExtractor has an Automator action which can be scripted through the shell.

Comment: Despite the caveats, that's the kind of answer I was looking for. A GUI bases solution is quite useless when you would like to convert hundreds of webarchives on a server.

Comment: This doesn't even extract the original HTML file, but converts it. It's really more like opening an HTML file in TextEdit and reexporting it.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a software. The software is almost as the same as the one in the link you provided.

https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20643/webarchive-folderizer

Mac OS X 10.2 Or Later : Intel / PPC

Comment: It worked great for me on El Capitan.