# How to extract Safari .webarchive file to folder, from command line?

Tags: safari, command-line, software-recommendation

Safari offers the `.webarchive` format to download a webpage, together with embedded resources (images, etc).  As described/linked in answers to [How do I turn a Safari Webarchive file into a folder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123437/how-do-i-turn-a-safari-webarchive-file-into-a-folder), there are several apps available to extract the contents of a `.webarchive` into a folder containing the individual files.  However, all the answers given are GUI apps (except for the `textutil` answer, which unfortunately doesn’t do what’s requested, as explained in its comments).  However, I would prefer a command-line solution, for easier scriptability etc.

**Is there a way to extract the contents of a `.webarchive` file from the command line?**

Comment: You might want to consider using something like SiteSucker, which will download all the linked resources for a site, thus cutting out the webarchive process.

Comment: @benwiggy a webarchive captures what is loaded in the browser window. SiteSucker simulates an extended browsing session through the whole site. Without setting a lot of restrictions (& knowing how to do so correctly), you always get a lot more than you want.

Answer (score 1):

[Web Archive Extractor](https://robrohan.github.io/WebArchiveExtractor/)

It's not a command line application but it does include an Automator workflow, and those *can* be run from the command line by running `/usr/bin/automator <path to workflow>`.

Comment: This doesn't work on my MBP M2 running Sonoma. I downloaded the project. It's quite outdated Obj-C code that will take some work to update.

Comment: That's a shame.

Comment: Yeah they all look broken. But it seems pretty easy to parse out the data from the bplist. I might do that as a side project.